# Does a creature take damage from Wall of Fire if it is moved before its turn?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, forced-movement, wizard, wall

Here's the scenario:

A wizard is separated in initiative order from his target by one or more creatures/PCs.

The wizard creates a Wall of Fire which occupies the space of his target creature.

Prior to the target creature's turn, another creature or PC forces the target to move outside of the wall's space.

Does the target creature ever take damage for having been in the wall's space?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As printed they would not. The spell explicitly states that damage is dealt under one of the following conditions:

- A creature starts its turn adjacent to the wall.
- A creature moves into the wall's space.
- A creature starts its turn within the wall's space.

None of those three things has occurred if the creature is pushed/pulled/slid out of the fire before the start of its turn.

Comment: Correct. Could be a good deal for the Wizard to delay his action until just before his target's turn.

Comment: @ErikBurigo great way to let someone spend his turn saving the ally instead of fighting.

Comment: @Zachiel. Delaying is not a waste of turns/actions: it only shifts the start of your turn some point of initiative in the future, but you are not giving up actions.

Comment: @ErikBurigo Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I thought your wizard was delaying to push/pull/slid an ally out of the spell's effect, instead of hitting villains.

Comment: @Zachiel. No problem :) I had some trouble in trying to understand what's wrong with my observation ;)